# Semi-Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I don't understand the principal idea of Semi-Riemannian Manifold. Why is that if I have a metric tensor $g$ on a smooth manifold $M$ that is a symmetric nondegenerate $(0, 2)$-tensor field on $M$ of constant index (metric tensor), I can define a scalar product on every tangent space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a generalized scalar product $g(X,Y)$ that may take negative values. This kind of thing is useful in relativity theory, for example. But it is not a familiar Euclidean scalar product!

Comment: Agreed. From engineering point of view, sometimes, it is impossible to define a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on some Lie groups of our interest, then one could go for a bi-invariant semi or pseudo Riemannian metric. A lot of symmetric spaces I deal with are unfortunately of this type.